# python selenium get latest coin value from tabel

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How to get the latest coin name from table

[image]

Let say we select First 2 coins and every time when I refresh the browser using while loop, I only want to get latest coin name in new list:

Example:

```
Coin 1:  XRPUSDT
Coin 2:  BNBUSDT
```

and next time when browser refresh `SOLUSDT` comes at position 2 and replace the `BNBUSDT`

What I tried for that:

```
coinlist = list()
count = 1
while True:
     driver.get('https://www.coingecko.com/en/exchanges/binance_futures')
     # get all coin in list
     container = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(text(), "Others")]/../../../div[@class="pb-4"]//tbody/tr')

    for data in container[:2]:
        splitdata = data.text.split(' ') 
        if count == 1:            
           coinlist .append(
            splitdata[0]
           )


        else:
            if splitdata[0] not in coinlist:
               coinlist.append(
                     splitdata[0]
               )
               #DISCORD BOT NOTIFICATION code
```

It works fine Until if BNBUSDT replace SOLUSDT again because that coin is already in list and I'm not able to get notification.

Comment: please, provide example of the output you have and the output you want to have.

Answer (score 0):

So get the latest coin notification what i did is as under:

```
coinlist = list()
minilist = list()
count = 1
while True:
      driver.get('https://www.coingecko.com/en/exchanges/binance_futures')
      # get all coin in list
      container = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(text(), 
      "Others")]/../../../div[@class="pb-4"]//tbody/tr')

    for data in container[:2]:
        splitdata = data.text.split(' ') 
       if count == 1:            
          coinlist.append(
          splitdata[0]
          )

          minilist.append(
                splitdata[0]
            )


      else:
         if splitdata[0] not in coinlist:
           minilist.append(
                splitdata[0]
            )
           #DISCORD BOT NOTIFICATION code
        else:
           minilist.append(
                splitdata[0]
            )
  coinlist.clear()    
  coinlist.extend(minilist)    
  minilist.clear()
```